# Combining two SQL Statements into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have written two SQL statements as I was unable to figure out how to solve my problem.

One called `get_ID` and the other `Save Record`. I wanted the save record to read and see if there was an I id entered in a field in a vb Front end and if there was not it was assign one for it but I was unable to figure this out here is what I have so far. It works but I know there should be a better way to do this. Help this this problem would be great

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Product_GetID] 
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @NewProductID as int

   /* Get New Record */
   SET @NewProductID = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ProductID) + 1, 1) FROM Product)

   SELECT 
      ISNULL(MAX(ProductID) + 1, 1) AS NewIDNo 
    FROM Product

    INSERT INTO Product (ProductID, CategoryID, Description, Price)
    VALUES (@NewProductID, 0, '', 0) 
END

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Product_SaveRecord] 
   @ProductID as int, 
   @CategoryID as tinyint, 
   @Description as varchar(80), 
   @FullDescription as varchar(240), 
   @Price as decimal(8, 2), 
   @MarkupPer as decimal(8, 2), 
   @LabourHours as decimal(8, 2), 
   @LabourRate as decimal(8, 2), 
   @Stock as integer
AS
BEGIN
     /* Update Record */
     UPDATE Product 
     SET CategoryID = @CategoryID,
         Description = @Description, 
         FullDescription = @FullDescription, 
         Price = @Price,
         MarkupPer = @MarkupPer,
         LabourHours = @LabourHours,
         LabourRate = @LabourRate,
         Stock = @Stock
     WHERE ProductID = @ProductID
END
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, but did you look at the [MERGE T-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. You've said you were unable to figure it out, but also that your code works. If your code works but you just want to make it better, your question may be better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: Yeah i know there could be a problem with this is there are alot of users on the ssystem as I think what coulod happen is that it could over lap as it has to go back and forward to complete the one task of saving a record

Comment: Looking into the SPs you have created, it seems that you are using the first SP to create a product and the other SP to update the product. If your problem is like insert the product record first and then update he record at some other time your procedures are fine, but if you want all the values at once why are you not entering those values while you are inserting the product record in the first SP itself?

Answer (score 0):

Below I have made a few changes to your code. I am sure there are more but this will help:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Product_SaveRecord] 
   @ProductID as int, 
   @CategoryID as tinyint, 
   @Description as varchar(80), 
   @FullDescription as varchar(240), 
   @Price as decimal(8, 2), 
   @MarkupPer as decimal(8, 2), 
   @LabourHours as decimal(8, 2), 
   @LabourRate as decimal(8, 2), 
   @Stock as integer
AS
BEGIN
    IF @ProductID IS NULL BEGIN
        SET @ProductID = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ProductID) + 1, 1) FROM Product)

        INSERT INTO Product (ProductID, CategoryID, Description, Price) --Add the rest of the columns
        VALUES (@NewId, @CategoryID, @Description, @Price) --Add the rest of the columns
    END ELSE BEGIN
        /* Update Record */
        UPDATE Product 
        SET CategoryID = @CategoryID,
            Description = @Description, 
            FullDescription = @FullDescription, 
            Price = @Price,
            MarkupPer = @MarkupPer,
            LabourHours = @LabourHours,
            LabourRate = @LabourRate,
            Stock = @Stock
        WHERE ProductID = @ProductID
    END
END
```

As you get more comfortable, you could use the MERGE method too, it is very similar.